# Is there some way to look at a user's previous usernames?

Tags: support, users, display-names

I'm quite happy with my user name and have never changed it (that I remember...?), but some users do change their names, and just often enough to cause me occasional confusion. I run into these slightly confusing situations in 1 out of 10-15 or so posts I look at, where one person is replying to a user that does not seem to exist in the previous comments or as the poster of the question/answer.

It could be that the comment I'm looking for was deleted, but several times, I've seen someone that has a similar enough user name or a comment which seems to be the cause of the response(s) that are slightly confusing me.

Is there a way to view someone's history of user names, so that if I suspect there is a reference, I can at least manually confirm it?

Here's the most recent example:

I believe the [comment being responded to](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/63016/how-to-benefit-from-company-disaster#comment-169580) (which is hidden until you expand comments on the question) is by "The Merry Misanthrope", but in the suspected responses I think people are referring to this account as `@KevinKrumwiede`. This question currently being less than a day old, it's not quite as likely that @KevinKrumwiede changed his/her user account's name as it is in situations where I'm viewing a question that is a year old or older, but it's obviously still possible.

Granted this is a minor annoyance in the grand scheme of things, but I wonder if I'm not the only one to notice and be slightly bothered by it, and whether there's a remedy for this annoyance?

Comment: I'm sure this is a dupe of something - in short, the answer is no: previous names of users are considered private and are only accessible by diamond moderators.

Comment: The general community cannot see past usernames. It can be confusing at times, but then it's like a detective novel, working out whom a person is referring to :D

Comment: @JonClements I am not stalking you ninja pup :D

Comment: @MsYvette - personally, I tend toward sci-fi, fantasy, or non-fiction - though they could incorporate mystery/detective stuff, it's not what I most enjoy...

Comment: @CodeJockey ah I see, well, how about developing the theory that the users have been replaced by alien abductors and they are attempting to hide their tracks? No good?

Comment: @MsYvette - I'm not sure what you're talking about. I'm [certainly not a spider](https://xkcd.com/1530/) if that's what you're intimating. Fingers and central nervous system working fine!

Comment: @CodeJockey hahahahaha love it! thanks